# CakePHP Load FullCalendar event model on controler

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

CakePHP 2.3

Trying to add **events** to the FullCalendar from the controller, but I can't get  the model to load

on my controller I have try:

```
App::import ('Events','FullCalendar');
```

And

```
$this->loadModel('FullCalendar.Events');
```

Also

```
App::uses('FullCalendar', 'Event');
```

But every time I try to call **event** I get Error: Call to undefined function find() 
This is the simple test Im doing to test if the model loaded

```
$result = $this->Event-find('all');
```

I read all the post first about loading a model but I must be making a simple mistake some where,please advise.